# Что возвращает $this->pivot, если много связей MtoM? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Прошу помощи, коллеги!

Не могли бы вы пояснить, как понять, что возвращает $this->pivot, если в моем случае для одной модели используется две промежуточные таблица, которые связывает эту модель с двумя другими? Возможности проверить на веб-сервере нету.

Нарисовал иллюстрацию, чтобы хоть как-то облегчить постановку вопроса.

Что вернет $this->pivot ---> PropertyOption или Order

Взято из гитхаб-репозитория, который я изучаю и там нету связи между Sku и Order в обратном порядке (может автор просто забыл), я предоставил в таком варианте, в котором это реализовано --> pivot-таблица как для Order, так и для PropertyOption создается

Метод, где $this->pivot, вызывается из модели Sku

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А `dd()` что говорит?

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси Нету возможности склонировать проект, не могли бы вы посмотреть, что на ваш взгляд хотя бы должно вернуть?

Comment: Скорее всего возвращает обект заказываемых позиций однотипного товара. Метод `getPriceForCount()` возвращает цену для количества. Соответственно `$this->pivot->count` - нечто иное как количество, а `$this->price` - цена. Для чегото более детального нужно как минимум ссылка на репозиторий того что вы изучаете.